# Golang - map data from one complex struct to another

Tags: xml, dictionary, struct, go

I'm using Go structs to represent two structurally different XML documents.
One XML document is the source of the data being processed, and the other XML document is the target that the source should map into.

I have both XML documents mapped out in Go structs already, and both know how to marshal/unmarshal an XML structure.

So currently I'm typing out each path in each struct, to map fields from the source, into fields in the target.

Is there a quicker way to perhaps initialize a new Target instance, using some sort of shorthand to ease the mapping of data? Keeping in mind these are complex nested structures, so a pattern I can follow "to the depths" would be excellent.

EDIT: Adding sample XML data structures

The Go structs that represent these XML structures are pretty much a one-to-one representation of the XML structure, where each level of nesting is a new struct type. The structs were generated programmatically and are quite spread out, so it would take excessive effort to represent the data structures here (I'm short on time).

SOURCE data file - reaches up to 8 nested elements deep. There can be multiple  elements, each of which will generate a new separate "TARGET" instance.

```
<orders>
  <order order=no="111222333">
    <customer>
      <customer-no>555444333</customer-no>
      <customer-email>test@test.com</customer-email>
      <billing-address>
        <first-name>Test</first-name>
        <last-name>User</last-name>
      </billing-address>
    </customer>
    <product-lineitems>
      <product-lineitem>
        <product-id>SomeProductSku</product-id>
        <product-name>SomeProductName</product-name>
        <base-price>40.00</base-price>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
      </product-lineitem>
    </product-lineitems>
  </order>
</orders>
```

TARGET data file - reaches up to 10 nested elements deep

```
<OrderCreateRequest orderType="SALES" requestId="bcHcsiaagLwM6aaadnXz7ifXZL">
    <Order customerOrderId="111222333" levelOfService="REGULAR">
        <Customer customerId="555444333">
            <Name>
                <LastName>User</LastName>
                <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
            </Name>
            <EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
        </Customer>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem id="item_0_1" webLineId="1">
                <ItemId>SomeProductSku</ItemId>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <Description>
                    <Description>SomeProductName</Description>
                </Description>
                <Pricing>
                    <Merchandise>
                        <UnitPrice>40.00</UnitPrice>
                    </Merchandise>
                </Pricing>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </Order>
</OrderCreateRequest>
```

EDIT 2: I'm also trying to solve for type mappings not matching up. Currently I'm casting each value type as I assign it, which makes me thing I'm really going about this the wrong way.
The XML<->struct representations are already built, so if it's just a matter of me needing to somehow initialize the Target struct using something like map[string]{interface{}} or whatever, let me know. Been quite awhile since I last looked at Go, so I'm certain I'm missing some better solution here

Comment: Can you provide your data structures?

Comment: @RoninDev, they're pretty large, so I'll provide snippets of each

Comment: @RoninDev, updated w/ basic sample XML. I can't include the Go structs themselves as they were generated programmatically, so running them down would take more time than I really have available right now.

Comment: Have you tried `xslt` instead golang solution? Maybe it will fit better

Comment: @RoninDev, there's programmatic transformation that has to occur as well, such as RSA decryption of several values, generated unique strings, etc. Due to those wrinkles, I didn't go w/ XSLT. It would've been a great fit for straight-up mapping/transformation though, I agree

Comment: The most important thing is the two structs need to have the same structure to map. Else, I'm thinking interface{} is the key. This is a [blog post](https://medium.com/code-zen/dynamically-creating-instances-from-key-value-pair-map-and-json-in-go-feef83ab9db2) that might give some idea.

Comment: Sounds like what you're doing is reasonable. You could separate out creating some subobjects into distinct functions. Also worth knowing, if you don't, that compound literals can be nested and can create struct pointers not just structs: http://play.golang.org/p/y7WZ2iX4Pc